# How to solve jqueryUi error: 'Microsoft Jscript runtimeerror '?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

Hi; i have a big problem jqueryui. i want to use jqueryui tab but error return öe. This error:

Microsoft Jscript runtimeerror: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined not a Function object. i have last version 1.8  . this error incredible. How to solve it?

[image]

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ChildSite_FullExtNet.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GenSystem.Models.MinuteSchedule>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function () {
          $("#tabs").tabs();
      });

  </script>


<%=Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the erros and try again.") %>
  <% using (Html.BeginForm())
     { 
  %>

     <%=Html.HiddenFor(q=>q.JobSchedulerId) %>
     <span><%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.JobName) %>: <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.JobName) %></span>
     <span><%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.StartDateTime) %>: <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.StartDateTime) %></span>
     <span><%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.EndDateTime) %>: <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.EndDateTime) %></span>
     <span><%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.RepeatCount) %>: <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.RepeatCount) %></span>
     <span><%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.RepeatInterval) %> :  <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.RepeatInterval)%></span>

 <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>

    <%} %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you show where you has included js files in your html may be in your master page please paste master page html

Comment: @rahul The error seems to indicate that he **hasn't** done that.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have not included the java script files in the correct order.The jquery library must be loaded before the libraries for the ui.This can be solved if you include the files in the correct order.